# What are "data-require" "data-semver" in HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, plunker

I have seen tags like this in HTML. What are these attributes?

**This is NOT a duplicate of the `data-*` question.**

**Edit:**
I am looking for these two specific attributes, not `data-*` in general, nor data-require**d**, as Google suggests. If you search the web, you can find these attributes are used in many places. I guess this is some like of dependency management software?

```
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.1.5"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.5.0" data-semver="0.5.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: @cimmanon, I am looking for  this specific attribute.. Is there any pre-processor / library / builder using this attrubte?

Comment: Voted to reopen. I would be interested in further answers to this question explaining the specific `data-require` attribute as used by many ng (angularjs) modules. The generic html5 explanations do not answer this question adequately imo.

Comment: For what its worth. This question was wrongly labelled as duplicate by cimmanon @felix-kling jukka-k-korpela rink-attendant-6 and greg

Comment: Great answer from @user1769113 This is the only reference I could find that data-require and data-semver are actually specific implementations by Plunker of the html5 custom data-* specification

Answer (score 94):

I was curious about this as well.  These appear to be data- attributes that are created by [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) when including external libraries in its editor. Since plunker is used heavily throughout the development community that is probably why you see it appearing a lot.

By themselves they don't do anything special, unless a library or service decides to use them.

The 'data-semver' attribute appears to be an implementation of [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)

To the best of my knowledge no libraries actually use them for any sort of dependency checking/loading.

Answer (score -5):

The `data-` attribute is new in [HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and can be used to store arbitrary (text) data. The part after the '-' can be chosen by the author of the document. So you could have an attribute called myAge on the image of a person: `<img src="imageOfMe.jpg" data-myAge="42" />`. It is mostly used to save data for javascript applications.

Comment: I am looking for  this specific attribute.. Is there any pre-processor / library / builder using this attribute?